# Add loading view controller before tableview shows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a tableView controller that loads my parsed XML data. It takes some time to do.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

CustomStringParser *customStringParser = [[CustomStringParser alloc] init];

// Set MORE logo in navigation bar
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation"]];

// Download and parse XML data
RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.morecobalt.co.uk/rss/?t=events"]]];

// Create an array to store each feed
eventsFeeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Loop through XML data
[rxml iterate:@"channel" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *supportElement) {
    [supportElement iterate:@"item" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *repElement) {

        // Assign element to string
        NSString *title = [repElement child:@"title"].text;
        NSString *subtitle = [repElement child:@"tagline"].text;
        NSString *description = [repElement child:@"description"].text;
        NSString *imageurl = [repElement child:@"image"].text;
        NSString *startDate = [repElement child:@"start_date"].text;
        NSString *endDate = [repElement child:@"end_date"].text;

        // Assign element value to MoreCobalt.h propertys
        currentFeed = [MoreCobaltEvents alloc];
        currentFeed.title = title;
        currentFeed.subtitle = subtitle;
        currentFeed.imageurl = imageurl;

        // DESCRIPTION FORMATTING
        description = [customStringParser parseHTML:description];
        description = [customStringParser parseLinesMultiple:description];
        description = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:description];
        currentFeed.description = description;

        // DATE FORMATTING
        currentFeed.startDate = [customStringParser formatDate:startDate];
        currentFeed.endDate = [customStringParser formatDate:endDate];

        // Add a new object to the feeds array
        [eventsFeeds addObject:currentFeed];
    }];
}];
}
```

While the data is been parsed I want to add a loading screen with a activity indicator on. Im guessing this is going to be a sub view. How can I do this?

NOTE: Im using storyboards. Image below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just drag an activity indicator component on your xib.
Declare a property in your .h file. Hook it up.

In your .m file in viewDidLoad call.

```
[self.activityIndicator starAnimating];
[self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

And then after your table loads call:

```
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

No need for subviews.

Comment: Im not able to add the activity indicator in the middle of the tableview. It automatically places just below my cell. This is not what I want. Thanks

Comment: If you put the right constraints in it, it can :-) You can put anything you want on top of something else in your interface.

Comment: The constraints seem to be locked.

Comment: If you can put a screenshot of Interface builder, it would help. Otherwise you can put the activity indicator at the center of the xib, click the "Resolve autolayout issues" button on bottom right in the xib area and select "Add missing constraints" and "Update All constraints in view"

Comment: Image uploaded. Please see above

Answer (score -1):

```
Write below code in **AppDelegate.h** 
 UIActivityIndicatorView *progressIndicator;
    UIView *progressIndicatorView;


Write below code in **AppDelegate.m** 

-(void) addProgressIndicator:(UIView *)parentView
{
    [self.progressIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];

        self.progressIndicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, parentView.frame.size.width,parentView.frame.size.height)];

        self.progressIndicatorView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
        self.progressIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((parentView.frame.size.width - 70) / 2,(parentView.frame.size.height - 70) / 2,70,70)];

    [self.progressIndicatorView addSubview:self.progressIndicator];
    [parentView addSubview:self.progressIndicatorView];
    [parentView bringSubviewToFront:self.progressIndicatorView];
    [self.progressIndicatorView bringSubviewToFront:self.progressIndicator];
    [self.progressIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [self.progressIndicator setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
    [self.progressIndicator stopAnimating];
    [self.progressIndicatorView setHidden:YES];
}

-(void) startProgressIndicator
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showProgressIndicator) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void) showProgressIndicator
{
    [self.progressIndicatorView setHidden:NO];
    [self.progressIndicator startAnimating];
}

-(void) stopProgressIndicator
{
    [self.progressIndicator stopAnimating];
    [self.progressIndicatorView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Call this methods where you want to show Progress Indicator,in viewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear .
Good Luck !!